# Javascript remove all characters by regex rules

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Who can help me with the following
I create a rule with regex and I want remove all characters from the string if they not allowed.

I tried something by myself but I get not the result that I want

```
document.getElementById('item_price').onkeydown = function() {
    var regex = /^(\d+[,]+\d{2})$/;
    if (regex.test(this.value) == false ) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(regex, "");
    }
}
```

The characters that allowed are numbers and one komma.
Remove all letters, special characters and double kommas.

If the user types k12.40 the code must replace this string to 1240

Who can help me to the right direction?

Comment: You need to be more clear. What characters are not allowed?

Comment: he said all characters, means all characters!

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu it looks like he wants to remove 'k' and '.', e.g. only allow numbers.

Comment: @Dshiz if thats what he wants why doesn't he just replace everything thats not a digit with "" (nothing). I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, why he doesn't chance everything but only numbers?

Comment: I edit my question which characters I want to remove.

Comment: RegExp is used with defined patterns. You seem to have defined completely random strings with commas or not commas that may or may not contain undesirable characters that may appear in any random order.

Comment: You should consider using the [HTML 5 pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern). That allows you to provide a RegExp pattern that ensures the user can only put text in the field that matches the requirement for the pattern. Then you can define `/\d{1,3}.\d{2}/` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely removes double occurrences of commas using regex, but keeps single ones.

```js
// This should end up as 1,23243,09
let test = 'k1,23.2,,43d,0.9';

let replaced  = test.replace(/([^(\d|,)]|,{2})/g, '')

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an easy way to have a single Regex behave like you want. You can use a function to determine what to replace each character with, though:

```js
// This should end up as 1232,4309 - allows one comma and any digits
let test = 'k12,3.2,,43,d0.9';

let foundComma = false;
let replaced  = test.replace(/(,,)|[^\d]/g, function (item) {
    if (item === ',' && !foundComma) {
      foundComma = true;
      return ',';
    } else {
      return '';  
    }
})

console.log(replaced);
```

This will loop through each non-digit. If its the first time a comma has appeared in this string, it will leave it. Otherwise, if it must be either another comma or a non-digit, and it will be replaced. It will also replace any double commas with nothing, even if it is the first set of commas - if you want it to be replaced with a single comma, you can remove the (,,) from the regex.

Comment: OP updated his question to reflect a single comma (but not double) and numbers. But that update came after your answer.

Comment: Thank you - just saw that. Removing this answer.